# Additional drop down box to Cognito Form entries listing

Tags: cognito-forms

On the entries page, there is a drop down for status. Am I able to add another three drop down boxes so I can say when the job was started and finished, and add any comments?

Answer (score 1):

In [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can mark any field as `Show This Field - Internally`, which will make the field or section only appear when you are managing entries through administration.  These fields are sent for email notifications (sent to you) but not sent for email confirmations (sent to your customers).  You can also trigger automatic email notifications and confirmations when you update entries, such as sending a followup email when the job is marked as finished.